# ECharts make the XAxis proportional to its values

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I need to update the xAxis of this chart to make it be proportional to its values:

[Here is my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tFAO.png)
As you can see the A Section is as wide as the B section even if the difference in X values from start to finish is roughfully ten fold (0.01 in A, 0.1 in B).

I need the A section to be 1/10 of the B section. Is there an Echart a settings to achieve this?

Here's a codepen of my current situation:
https://codepen.io/dariooo512/pen/vYawBMb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Smoothed Line Chart - Apache ECharts Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container"></div>
  <script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```
var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: 'canvas',
  useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

const xData = [
0.0100000000000000,
0.0107977516232770,
0.0116591440117983,
0.0125892541179416,
0.0135935639087852,
0.0146779926762206,
0.0158489319246111,
0.0171132830416178,
0.0184784979742229,
0.0199526231496887,
0.0215443469003188,
0.0232630506715362,
0.0251188643150957,
0.0271227257933202,
0.0292864456462523,
0.0316227766016837,
0.0341454887383359,
0.0368694506451957,
0.0398107170553497,
0.0429866234708227,
0.0464158883361277,
0.0501187233627272,
0.0541169526546463,
0.0584341413373517,
0.0630957344480192,
0.0681292069057960,
0.0735642254459640,
0.0794328234724280,
0.0857695898590893,
0.0926118728128792,
0.0999999999999999,
0.1079775162327708,
0.1165914401179830,
0.1258925411794166,
0.1359356390878524,
0.1467799267622068,
0.1584893192461112,
0.1711328304161779,
0.1847849797422289,
0.1995262314968877,
0.2154434690031881,
0.2326305067153623,
0.2511886431509577,
0.2712272579332025,
0.2928644564625232,
0.3162277660168375,
0.3414548873833597,
]

const yData = [
  0.163994337909158,
0.164355359005510,
0.164781529248110,
0.165290711360058,
0.165888614999721,
0.166599912595426,
0.167449496368629,
0.168470163071883,
0.169710786849251,
0.171197399817278,
0.172712533758993,
0.174671841558769,
0.176975558012239,
0.180294513617511,
0.184327422956864,
0.191100453431249,
0.200522213979933,
0.211754773758690,
0.216565431261549,
0.2505493351851847,
0.326466853585988,
0.347298734251199,
0.3523985766254678,
0.373650615601135,
0.311629700205303,
0.280092084112155,
0.250131726901599,
0.273316888213822,
0.266613651947510,
0.317070017440979,
0.400477619240458,
0.3590975138843978,
0.4310041008366142,
0.5090963720150549,
0.4907638864448018,
0.5406581161637817,
0.56051067203831806,
0.5071383683330877,
0.5355916724605659,
0.5355408618682007,
0.3839169258278131,
0.2773418659785273,
0.2949077335148602,
0.2394754641244239,
0.2036052621075644,
0.2106189314544600,
0.2395847208235534,
]

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: xData
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: yData,
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true
    }
  ]
};

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xAxis` is a **category axis**, which is not a good choice for what you have to do...

You should use a **value axis** instead:

```js
const data = [
  [ 0.0100000000000000, 0.163994337909158 ],
  [ 0.0107977516232770, 0.164355359005510 ],
  [ 0.0116591440117983, 0.164781529248110 ],
  [ 0.0125892541179416, 0.165290711360058 ],
  [ 0.0135935639087852, 0.165888614999721 ],
  [ 0.0146779926762206, 0.166599912595426 ],
  [ 0.0158489319246111, 0.167449496368629 ],
  [ 0.0171132830416178, 0.168470163071883 ],
  [ 0.0184784979742229, 0.169710786849251 ],
  [ 0.0199526231496887, 0.171197399817278 ],
  [ 0.0215443469003188, 0.172712533758993 ],
  [ 0.0232630506715362, 0.174671841558769 ],
  [ 0.0251188643150957, 0.176975558012239 ],
  [ 0.0271227257933202, 0.180294513617511 ],
  [ 0.0292864456462523, 0.184327422956864 ],
  [ 0.0316227766016837, 0.191100453431249 ],
  [ 0.0341454887383359, 0.200522213979933 ],
  [ 0.0368694506451957, 0.211754773758690 ],
  [ 0.0398107170553497, 0.216565431261549 ],
  [ 0.0429866234708227, 0.2505493351851847 ],
  [ 0.0464158883361277, 0.326466853585988 ],
  [ 0.0501187233627272, 0.347298734251199 ],
  [ 0.0541169526546463, 0.3523985766254678 ],
  [ 0.0584341413373517, 0.373650615601135 ],
  [ 0.0630957344480192, 0.311629700205303 ],
  [ 0.0681292069057960, 0.280092084112155 ],
  [ 0.0735642254459640, 0.250131726901599 ],
  [ 0.0794328234724280, 0.273316888213822 ],
  [ 0.0857695898590893, 0.266613651947510 ],
  [ 0.0926118728128792, 0.317070017440979 ],
  [ 0.0999999999999999, 0.400477619240458 ],
  [ 0.1079775162327708, 0.3590975138843978 ],
  [ 0.1165914401179830, 0.4310041008366142 ],
  [ 0.1258925411794166, 0.5090963720150549 ],
  [ 0.1359356390878524, 0.4907638864448018 ],
  [ 0.1467799267622068, 0.5406581161637817 ],
  [ 0.1584893192461112, 0.56051067203831806 ],
  [ 0.1711328304161779, 0.5071383683330877 ],
  [ 0.1847849797422289, 0.5355916724605659 ],
  [ 0.1995262314968877, 0.5355408618682007 ],
  [ 0.2154434690031881, 0.3839169258278131 ],
  [ 0.2326305067153623, 0.2773418659785273 ],
  [ 0.2511886431509577, 0.2949077335148602 ],
  [ 0.2712272579332025, 0.2394754641244239 ],
  [ 0.2928644564625232, 0.2036052621075644 ],
  [ 0.3162277660168375, 0.2106189314544600 ],
  [ 0.3414548873833597, 0.2395847208235534 ]
];

let option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data,
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true
    }
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#chart-container {
  width 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart-container"></div>
```

Is it the expected result?

Take a look at the documentation: [xAxis.type](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.type)